# How to add group level action/events button in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ui-grid

I have some data , which will be displayed in ng-grid groupwise. For some of the groups i need to provide some actions like.

1) save particular group data    [Save button]

2) Do some opertions with that group data [ Test Button].

I tried in google search but not find any releate information.
How can we do this ?

Comment: Try this one : https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/ else, you need to put some code here which you have tried.

Comment: Hi @NaveedRamzan
thank you, but my requriement is not "click-to-edit or edit-in-place". 
My case is static button should be present for each group

Comment: I'm voting to close because it is not clear what you are asking